# MS Word updating links: Why does changing a .LinkFormat property reset field Index

Tags: vba, ms-word

I hope my first post will be OK and not offend (I've tried to follow the guide and done a lot of searching).

I've modified the below code from Greg Maxey (https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/word_fields.html) to update links in my Word document to an Excel workbook.  It seems to be the most used code for this purpose.  The reason I changed his code was to try to do away with the need to have a counter variable like i, and using a `For i = 1 to .Fields.Count Then... Next i` structure.

When I run it as is, it gets stuck in a loop only updating the first field in the Word document.  To see this, I put in the `Debug.Print wrdField.Index` line.  It repeatedly outputs 1, so it is not moving to the `Next wrdField` as I expect (the code actually just used `Next`, but it's the same result if I use `Next wrdField`).

When I comment out `.AutoUpdate = False`, it works properly:

```
Public Sub UpdateExternalLinksToCurrentFolder()

Dim wrdDocument As Word.Document
Dim wrdField As Word.Field
Dim strCurrentLinkedWorkbookPath, strNewLinkedWorkbookPath As String
Dim strCurrentLinkedWorkbookName, strNewLinkedWorkbookName As String
Dim strCurrentLinkedWorkbookFullName, strNewLinkedWorkbookFullName As String
Dim strThisDocumentPath As String

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler_UpdateExternalLinksToCurrentFolder

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wrdDocument = ActiveDocument
strThisDocumentPath = wrdDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
strNewLinkedWorkbookPath = strThisDocumentPath


With wrdDocument
    For Each wrdField In .Fields
       With wrdField
            If .Type = wdFieldLink Then
                With .LinkFormat

                     Debug.Print wrdField.Index

                     strCurrentLinkedWorkbookPath = .SourcePath & Application.PathSeparator
                     strCurrentLinkedWorkbookName = .SourceName
                     strNewLinkedWorkbookName = strCurrentLinkedWorkbookName
                     strNewLinkedWorkbookFullName = strNewLinkedWorkbookPath & strNewLinkedWorkbookName
                    .AutoUpdate = False
                End With
            .Code.Text = VBA.Replace(.Code.Text, Replace(strCurrentLinkedWorkbookPath, "\", "\\"), Replace(strNewLinkedWorkbookPath, "\", "\\"))
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With


Set wrdDocument = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
```

Can anyone tell my why it's behaving this way?  When I set `.AutoUpdate = False`, am I changing something about the link field or doing something to the Word document that causes the .wrdField.Index to reset to 1?  I can't find anything online documenting this behavior and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, what's happening is that Word *recreates* the content and the field. The orginal linked content is removed and new content inserted. So that essentially destroys the field and recreates it. A user won't notice this, but VBA does.

When dealing with a loop situation that uses an index and the looped items are being removed, it's therefore customary to loop *backwards* (from the end of the document to the beginning). Which cannot be done with For...Each.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, that makes sense.  Does it only happen in specific situations (e.g. changing the .AutoUpdate property)?  Just using `.Fields.Update`, or  `Replace(.Code.Text...)` doesn't seem to have the same effect.

Comment: I really don't know, in detail @Punter. This is just something I've picked up over the years in discussions with MS technicians with similar issues (such as what happens when content controls update).